# Avoid same image to display more than onece at the same time while displaying randomly

Tags: c#, .net

I am using this code To display the images randomly in 3 picture boxes at a time using timer ,Now I am testing it with 5 images in my folder ,intially it display different images properly in 3 of the picture boxes but later same image comes in 2 of the picture boxes or even 3 of them display same image ,how I can avoid displaying same image at the same time in more than one picture box

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        List<String> filesToShow = new List<string>();
        List<PictureBox> pictureBoxes;
        string LoginName;
        public Form2(string userName)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.LoginName = userName;
            label1.Text = "Welcome " + userName;
            timer2 = new Timer();
            pictureBoxes = new List<PictureBox> {
            pictureBox3,
            pictureBox4,
            pictureBox5
        };
            // Setup timer
            timer2.Interval = 5 * 1000; //1000ms = 1sec
            timer2.Tick += new EventHandler(timer2_Tick);
            timer2.Start();
            panelHide = panel4;

        }
        public static Panel panelHide = new Panel();

        private void ShowRandomImages()
        {
            foreach (var pictureBox in pictureBoxes)
            {
                if (filesToShow != null && !filesToShow.Any())
                {
                    filesToShow = GetFilesToShow();
                }

                if (filesToShow != null && filesToShow.Any()) // If any files then allow the code to delete the shown images
                {
                    int index = random.Next(0, filesToShow.Count);
                    string fileToShow = filesToShow[index];
                    pictureBox.ImageLocation = filesToShow[index];
                    filesToShow.RemoveAt(index);
                }
            }
        }
        private List<String> GetFilesToShow()
        {
            String str = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
            string path = str + "\\Image\\";
            return Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.jpg", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).ToList();
        }
        private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender == timer2)
            {
             ShowRandomImages();
            }

        }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any Help

Comment: `Random` and `controlling flow` both are contradictory. Redesign your algo.

Comment: Try to isolate the problems of randomization, file IO, timing, display, and excluding current items into independent methods. One of the problems is that everything is is one jumble of code. I was starting an answer along these lines but the question got closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple solution is to create a list with the selected images and check them before show a new image.

```
private void ShowRandomImages()
{
    List<int> selectedImages = new List<int>();
    foreach (var pictureBox in pictureBoxes)
    {
        if (filesToShow != null && !filesToShow.Any())
        {
            filesToShow = GetFilesToShow();
        }

        if (filesToShow != null && filesToShow.Any()) // If any files then allow the code to delete the shown images
        {
            int index = -1;
            if (filesToShow.Count >= pictureBoxes.Count)
            {
                bool bOk = false;
                while( !bOk )
                { 
                    index = random.Next(0, filesToShow.Count);
                    bOk = selectedImages.IndexOf(index) == -1;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                index = random.Next(0, filesToShow.Count);
            }

            selectedImages.Add(index);
            string fileToShow = filesToShow[index];
            pictureBox.ImageLocation = filesToShow[index];
            filesToShow.RemoveAt(index);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It is showing me this error `The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List<int>.Find(System.Predicate<int>)' has some invalid arguments` for this `selectedImages.Find(index)`

Comment: I have updated the code to fix this error.

Comment: I dont know why but It is looping near that while loop only for index 0 to 5 and images are not getting displayed ,I am not getting it

Comment: I'm sorry, I have write the bOk check bad. I have correct it.

Comment: I tried Still Images are reapiting and displaying more than once

Comment: I have check the code and It works fine. The unique situation that can repeat images is that there are less images than pictures, and the code execution go for the `else` way. If you can check it, only put a breakpoint after the `selectedImages.Add(index);` line and check if the index values are more than once.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35694/discussion-between-durga-and-superarce)

Answer (score 0):

Surely, bug happens when you display last image in your `filesToShow` list so the list becomes empty causing to execute

```
if (filesToShow != null && !filesToShow.Any())
{
    filesToShow = GetFilesToShow();
}
```

after that your `filesToShow` have all previously removed images, so they can be displayed again.